# Spark RDD find ratio of for key-value pairs

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

My rdd contains key-value pairs such as this:

```
(key1, 5),
(key2, 10),
(key3, 20),
```

I want to perform a map operation that associates each key with its respect ratio in the entire rdd, such as this:

```
(key1, 5/35),
(key2, 10/35),
(key3, 20/35),
```

I am struggling to find a method to do this using standard functions, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the sum and divide each value by the sum:

```
from operator import add

rdd = sc.parallelize([('key1', 5), ('key2', 10), ('key3', 20)])
total = rdd.values().reduce(add)
rdd2 = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: x/total)

rdd2.collect()
# [('key1', 0.14285714285714285), ('key2', 0.2857142857142857), ('key3', 0.5714285714285714)]
```

In Scala it would be

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("key1", 5), ("key2", 10), ("key3", 20)))
val total = rdd.values.reduce(_+_)
val rdd2 = rdd.mapValues(1.0*_/total)

rdd2.collect
// Array[(String, Double)] = Array((key1,0.14285714285714285), (key2,0.2857142857142857), (key3,0.5714285714285714))
```